# SyntaxError at JSON.parse - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am making a project using ReactJS and LoopBack, and a part of the code brings me some problems.

Here's the block code:
(It's part of a React Component called Common.js)

```
export const getUser = () => {
    const userStr = sessionStorage.getItem('user');
    if (userStr) 
    {return JSON.parse(userStr);}
    else return null;
}
```

This is the exception that throws me the code:

**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
getUser
C:/Users/anon/Desktop/Project/client_src/src/Utils/Common.js:4**

```
  1 | export const getUser = () => {
  2 |     const userStr = sessionStorage.getItem('user');
  3 |     if (userStr) 
> 4 |     {return JSON.parse(userStr);}
  5 |     else return null;
  6 | }
  7 |
```

I previously fixed it making this:

```
export const getUser = () => {
const userStr = JSON.stringify(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
    if (userStr){
    return JSON.parse(userStr);}
    else return null;
```

And it temporaly fixed the previous exception but it brought me some problems later when I wanted to get the username calling it from Dashboard.js Component.

Dashboard.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { getUser, removeUserSession } from '../Utils/Common';

const Dashboard = (props) => {
  const user = getUser();
  
  const handleLogout = () => {
    removeUserSession();
    props.history.push('/home');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>¡Welcome {user.username}!</h1>
      <br></br>
      <input
      type="button" 
      value="Logout" 
      className="btn btn-primary mb-2" 
      onClick={handleLogout}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
export default Dashboard;
```

The problem with this code is when I call {user.username} because it returns me nothing, as it couldn't read the JSON data.

(username is a key from the JSON data of the user)

Comment: Have you logged what's in `userStr` to see what data you're trying to parse?

Comment: Your "fix" fixes the error because the value is likely an empty string or null. May be you should take a look at what is adding this data to session storage. Do the keys match? Is the value being stored valid.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in saved session storage data.

You can't save objects directly to sessionStorage, you have to `JSON.stringify` them:

`sessionStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify({"name":"John"}));`

And then when you retrieve it, you will have to `JSON.parse` (as you did):

`let user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'))`

Comment: Sorry but I'm a bit new at this, what should I put on stringify parameters instead of hardcoded values? I need to get the name of the user that is logging.  (userStrg is returning me "undefined")

Comment: You should put `sessionStorage.setItem('user', ... )` into your Login functional. Somewhere where you are making an API call to your server to retrieve the logged-in user. It's hard to tell where exactly you should put that because I can't see the Login part in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the userStr content.

```
export const getUser = () => {
    const userStr = sessionStorage.getItem('user');
    console.log(userStr)
    if (userStr) 
    {return JSON.parse(userStr);}
    else return null;
}
```

After that you can check the syntax is matched with Json format.

If you can show me the this data content, we can solve this problem.

When it detects invalid JSON, it throws a JSON Parse error.

For example, one of the most common typos or syntax errors in JSON is adding an extra comma separator at the end of an array or object value set.

Comment: I debugged it and userStr is "undefined"

Comment: The error created b/c you tried to parsing undefined data.

You can add the validation in this line.

`{return userSrt?JSON.parse(userStr):{};}`

And you need to make the validation per step.

`condition? yes : no;`

I hope this can help you.

Thank you